# Returning a bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, return

I have an interface with a method that returns a bounded wildcard:

```
public Collection<? extends CacheableObject> retrieveConnections(CacheableObject element);
```

This interface is being implemented by a class name `PersistentAbstraction` that returns a `CacheableObject`:

```
public Collection<? extends CacheableObject> retrieveConnections(CacheableObject element) {
    Collection<CacheableObject> connections = new HashSet<CacheableObject>();
    for(CacheableRelation relation : connectedElements) {
        if(relation.contains(element)) {
            connections.add(relation.getRelatedElement(element));
        }
    }
    return connections;
}
```

And now I have an implementation of `CacheableObject` called `User` and a class that has an instance of `PersistentAbstraction`. I am trying to do the following:

```
public Collection<User> retrieveConnections(User user) {
    Collection<User> collection = (Collection<User>) persistentAbstraction.retrieveConnections(user);
    return collection;
}
```

But it says:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Collection<capture#1-of ? extends CacheableObject> to Collection<User>
```

I am not sure what is the reason behind that warning. Isn't User a CacheableObject? What does the warning mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retrieveConnections` returns a `Collection<? extends CacheableObject>`. This could be a `Collection<User>` but there is no way for the compiler to know this as it could be a `Collection<OtherClass>` where `OtherClass` is some other class implementing `CacheableObject`.

There are several ways to fix this. One would be to make `retrieveConnections` a generic method with signature

```
public <T extends CacheableObject> Collection<T> retrieveConnections(T element)
```

(You will need to modify the body of the method accordingly). Then `persistentAbstraction.retrieveConnections(user)` will have type `Collection<User>` and there will be no need for the cast.

Answer (score 3):

The error basically means that you cannot assign `Collection<? extends CacheableObject>` to `Collection<User>` and that's because there's no guarantee that at runtime the collection objects will be of type `User`.

A `Collection<? extends CacheableObject>` reference may very well point a collection holding items of type `AnotherCacheableObject` where `AnotherCacheableObject` *implements* `CacheableObject`.